# Is a quantum harmonic oscillator always infinite dimensional?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian

Let us assume we have a quantum particle in a harmonic potential with the Hamiltonian

$$H = \sum_n n \omega |n\rangle\langle n|$$

If I am not mistaken.

Now when talking about harmonic oscillators it is most of the times not mentioned that this sum $\sum_n$ should in fact go from $0$ to $\infty$.

So to my understanding the full, proper way would be to write

$$H = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} n \omega |n\rangle\langle n|$$

if we are talking about a quantum harmonic oscillator which would have a similar form to [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/HarmOsziFunktionen.png), with the only difference being that the energy gaps in my example are $\omega$ apart from neighbours.

So now when I would consider a **finite Hamiltonian**

$$H = \sum^{d}_n  n\omega |n\rangle\langle n|$$

then this would be no longer be per definition a harmonic oscillator. It would be a finite-dimensional quantum system with equally spaced energy levels that can be thought of as a truncated harmonic oscillator.

Is that correct?

Comment: $H = \sum_{n=1}^N i \omega_n (a^\dagger_n a_n)$ does not represent a harmonic oscillator. It represents $N$ harmonic oscillators.

Comment: The answer to your very last equation is "yes", provided you substitute $\omega (i+1/2)$ for your hardly meaningful $i\omega_i$.

Comment: Why is $\omega(i + 1/2)$ so much better than $i \omega_i$?

Comment: @DanielSank
That is good to know. I have removed that part. But the question still holds: Is it implicitly assumed when one writes $H =\sum_i i \omega i \mid i \rangle \langle i \mid$ that the sum goes from $0$ to infinity when it describes a harmonic oscillator?

Comment: Please don't use $i$ as a variable in quantum theory where it's potentially also used as $\sqrt{-1}$.  It's bad discipline.  Eventually people trip up doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Using an index $i$ on $\omega$ is misleading. Either the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian are $i \omega$ or $\omega_i$, if $\omega_i=\omega (i+1/2)$. Using both makes the Hamiltonian different from that of a harmonic oscillator. The question should be edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If $\vert n\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat H$ with energy 
$(n+1/2)\hbar\omega$, it is easily verified that 
$\hat a^\dagger \vert n\rangle $ is also an eigenstate with energy $(n+3/2)\hbar\omega$.  Moreover, as $\hat a^\dagger \vert n\rangle =
\sqrt{n+1}\vert n+1\rangle $ it is also clear that the ladder of states of increasing $n$ never stops, i.e. $n$ is unbounded.

This is different from angular momentum, where 
$\hat L_\pm\vert \ell m\rangle =\sqrt{(\ell\mp m)(\ell \pm m+1)}\vert \ell,m\pm 1\rangle$.  Since the factor $\sqrt{(\ell\mp m)(\ell \pm m+1)}$ becomes $0$ when 
$\hat L_+\vert \ell,\ell\rangle$ or when $L_-\vert \ell,-\ell\rangle$; in the case of angular momentum, the ladder of states stops and the possible values of $m$ are $-\ell \le m\le \ell$.

Comment: I'd like to add a remark. You also need to check that $\langle n+1 | n+1 \rangle \neq 0$, otherwise they would be states orthogonal to everything and thus could be consistently truncated from the Hilbert space.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero
I see but what if I assume that energies $E_n = n \hbar  \omega$ are the eigenvalues to the eigenstates $\mid n\rangle$ ? This would work aswell, no ?

Comment: see this paper Atakishiyev, N. M., G. S. Pogosyan, and K. B. Wolf. "Finite models of the oscillator." Physics of Particles and Nuclei 36.3 (2005): 247-265. available here: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kurt_Wolf2/publication/296616388_Finite_models_of_the_oscillator/links/0a85e53a081bc69845000000/Finite-models-of-the-oscillator.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> It would be a finite-dimensional quantum system with equally spaced energy levels that can be thought of as a truncated harmonic oscillator.
>
> Is that correct?

Yes, that is correct. It's an interesting enough system (see e.g. [this shameless plug](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.5724)), and 'truncated harmonic oscillator' is probably the best name for it.